# UFW reload and disable/enable work but not just enable

Tags: ufw

I have a test linode server (Ubuntu 17.10) for playing around. If the server is rebooted I need to either run

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

or

```
sudo ufw reload
```

to be able to see the web pages on that server.

If I just run:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

I cannot see the web pages from a remote computer.

I'm also curious why I have to do anything with ufw after a reboot as the rules are there. Why do they need a kick start.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look in `/var/log/ufw.log` and see if you can find some useful information there. Are the requests actually being blocked?

Comment: Thanks Mikael.   I checked the log and after a reboot I can see the requests that I'm making are blocked until I run either disable/enable or renew.  Just enable doesn't work.  I did fine this: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319291/ufw-blocks-most-ports-until-disabled-and-re-enabled-after-reboot).  So other folks are seeing the issue.

Comment: I've created the service suggested in the post I listed above and that works, but I'm not convinced that's how ufw is supposed to work.

Comment: Upgrading to Bionic 18.04 didn't help.